# Magento API from magento1 or 2 to magento2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, api

I want to have an api to transfer data from magento1 and magento2 to magento2.1 real time
I mean that want to change my magento2.1 price field if it changed from magento 1 or 2 websites
could you please explain me fully how should i do?